# chruby not changing to the proper version of ruby according to the value in .ruby-version on new terminal tab

Tags: ruby, chruby

I am using source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh to auto change ruby to the version in .ruby-version, but unfortunately this only works on cd.

When I open an new tab in my mac terminal, it opens to the same directory I was in in the previous tab, but auto change does not work. My solution to this is to `cd ..` and the `cd` back in, which triggers the change. This is tiresome, obviously.

I tried to manually call the function `chruby_auto` in the new tab, but this has no effect.

Can someone offer a solution of how to get my ruby version updated in this case? I would prefer an automatic solution, but will settle for a command to call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually nevermind, I traced this back to an issue in the order of these calls in my .bashrc

***Incorrect:***

```
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
chruby ruby-2.3.0
```

I turns out you must call the auto line AFTER the default line. Note that the default line must be after the chruby.sh line, as well.

***Correct:***

```
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
chruby ruby-2.3.0 # default order important, if comes after auto.sh, will undo the auto change
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
```

So just leaving this answer here for posterity I guess

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your issue, it sounds like you want a `~/.ruby-version` file (different to the `.ruby-version` file in your project), so that you can determine what version of Ruby you want to use by default when opening a new terminal window (this value would then be overridden by a project `.ruby-version` file if it exists).  For example, in my `~/.bashrc`, I have:

```
if [[ -e /usr/local/share/chruby ]]; then
  # Load chruby
  source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
  # Allow auto-switching of Ruby version when
  # directory has a .ruby-version file
  source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh
fi
```

My `~/.ruby-version` just contains `2.3.1`, and there isn't a need to call `chruby` explicitly in `~/.bashrc`.  For more information, see the [Default Ruby section of `chruby`'s README file](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#default-ruby).

Comment: no, there just seemed to be a case when auto switch wasn't working, but it actually was, it was just being undone by the order of things in my bashrc